# Cordova - Write to a json file in the www directory

Tags: json, cordova

I already read the cordova documentation https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html#read-a-file- about how to create and store files, but I do not seem to find a way of read or writing to a file in the www/ directory.

Well, I can read the file by using an ajax call, but I cannot write to it, Is there any way of doing it?

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs){
     console.log(fs);
     fs.root.getFile("www/json/instalation.json", {create: false, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
              console.log("fileEntry is file?" + fileEntry.isFile.toString()); }, function(){console.log('error');});
                    }, function(){});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot write a file back to the `www` directory, any more than any web application could write a file back to the server web root. You'll have to write the file to the local file system, or alternatively you could consider storing the data in local storage or IndexedDB.